# Unable to open settings in LG Android phones grammatically

Tags: java, android, security, settings, fingerprint

I am trying to open fingerprint settings in all phones. I am successful to do in Samsung but unable to open in LG phones my code is below.

```
    private void gotoSecuritySettings(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
            fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
    }

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private void startFingerprintEnrollment(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_FINGERPRINT_ENROLL);
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE_FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMENT);
    }
```

Comment: Kindly help guys as my project is in process and I have to deliver to the client..